# Font-Face use absolute path

Tags: css, font-face

Is it possible to use an absolute path with `@fontace?` I have the follow directory-structure:

```
-HP
|--font
|  |- Monoton.woff
|  |- Monoton.eot
|--css
|  |- font.css
|  |- fontface.css
|--html
   |-index.html
```

Defined the font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-familiy: Monoton;
    src: url('../font/Monoton.woff') format('woff'); // EDIT: Change fonts to font the name of th woff-file
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and used it in the css as class monoton:

```
@import url('fontFace.css');

.monoton {
    font-familiy: Monoton, cursive;
    font-size: 1.875em;
    color: rgba(0, 200, 0, 1);
}
```

but it doesn't works in chrome, Firefox and co. Can somebody explain me why?
I have put the `fontFace.css` and all font-files in the html-directory. Now it will work..

Comment: Please give a link to your page so that we can see what happens.

Comment: Actuell it's only offline available... In few days I add a link to the website

Comment: Please, show me where do you use <absolute path>?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all that's *relative path* and **not** *absolute path*, absolute path means using like `http://whatever.com/fonts/font_file.woff` and secondly it doesn't work because you have a folder called `font` where as you are using `../fonts/`.

Also, I see that file names do not match, you have a file called `Monton.woff` but you are using `Monoton-Regular-webfont.woff`, you need to change the file names accordingly and use the snippet below

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Monoton;
    src: url('../font/Monoton-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

---

You can also use these fonts directly from google by including the below snippet in your stylesheet

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PaEJq/)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Monoton';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Monoton'), local('Monoton-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/monoton/v4/AKI-lyzyNHXByGHeOcds_w.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: @user2457241 So I will need a demo, cuz that's all I can help by seeing the provided codee

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dBskw/ is my used code but I don't know how i can add the files to fiddle.. so I can you only show my used code

Comment: The Monoton-Style is only one of my used and not all I used are available on google

Comment: @user2457241 So I won't be able to make out unless you upload it on some server or provide me files using dropbox

Comment: I have send you an e-mail

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo :

```
font-familiy: Monoton;
```